# Detecting DNS tunneling

Tags: network, firewalls, dns, ids, tunneling

I have been trying to detect/establish `DNS` tunneling. First of all I logged out of my user account of the captive portal. Findings:

`$ nslookup <somesite> // works fine
$ ping <somesite> // Destination Net Prohibited`

Why the outputs of `nslookup` and `ping` are different. On the back they both are using **ICMP** protocol, I can't get that.

Moreover, since `nslookup` is working fine; so the `DNS` queries are working fine. I tried doing `DNS` tunneling by connecting to a`VPN` Server running over port 25000 using `UDP`. I was able to do `netcat` to the port and I was able to connect to the VPN while I am logged in. But when I am logged out it does not connect. So, what does it indicate ?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/495759/why-is-ping-unable-to-resolve-a-name-when-nslookup-works-fine) may be relevant to your first query.

Comment: @Jedi I on a linux system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS does not use ICMP. It uses UDP (and rarely TCP) port 53.

The firewall/router the captive portal contols either does not block that port or it *is* the DNS server and is responding.

All other traffic are of course blocked until you log in.

Response to [comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129108/detecting-dns-tunneling/129109?noredirect=1#comment239645_129109):

For 2), UDP has no session control, i.e. it just sends a packet without checking if it has been received or if there's even any one to receive it. So it's impossible to know if a connection worked unless you managed to receive some response from the server based on the data you send.

If you did receive response, it is possible UDP packets are entirely unblocked (which I'd consider as a poor design for a captive portal.)

For 1), ping under different systems use different mechanism. Many use ICMP Echo messages, but some attempt TCP connections or send special UDP packets to force a response. Sometimes firewall rules are not set up to block them consistently, so ping is not always trustworthy in unusual network setups.

Comment: I have two queries : 
1) Why `ping` is not working ?
2) When I am logged out, I can do `netcat` to other servers, so basically I am sending UDP packets ?

Comment: For 1), it just doesn't make any sense to allow ping through when all other traffic are blocked. DNS has to be allowed to make the captive portal work. 2) what do you mean by "other servers"? Are they in the same network or are they on the Internet? What parameters you pass to `nc`?

Comment: 1) I mean`nslookup` is working, so why not `ping`, do they function differently ?
2) I did netcat on an external server (internet) 
```
$ nc -vz -u 176.126.237.217 25000
```

Comment: Okay, I got the `ping` part.

Comment: Thanks, great help ! So, can you suggest any other ways to bypass such systems :) , I cannot do `ARP poisoning` because I am under a dedicated APC(a wireless receiver of broadband signal and acts as a router, I do have logins for it admin panel though :p) and I am the single user under it.

Comment: Do you mean from a system defense point of view or from a user trying to get free internet pov?

Comment: Well, from a system point of view for sure. They have bounty programs !

Comment: There could be lots of holes in the captive portal pages or in other services in the device service them, but the idea of blocking all traffic until logged in is sound and easy to implement correctly.

Comment: Finally I got succeeded, http://black-perl.in/dns-tunneling/